# How to verify multiple method calls with different params

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following method that I wish to verify behaviour on.

```
public void methodToTest(Exception e, ActionErrors errors) {
    ...

    errors.add("exception.message", 
            ActionMessageFactory.createErrorMessage(e.toString()));

    errors.add("exception.detail",
            ActionMessageFactory.createErrorMessage(e.getStackTrace()[0].toString()));

    ...
}
```

In my @Test class I was hoping to do something like this to verify that `errors.add()` is called with "exception.message" and again with "exception.detail"

```
verify(errors).add(eq("exception.message"), any(ActionError.class));
verify(errors).add(eq("exception.detail"), any(ActionError.class));
```

however Mockito complains as follows

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
actionErrors.add(
    "exception.message",
    <any>
);

Actual invocation has different arguments:
actionErrors.add(
    "exception.detail",
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionError@38063806
);
```

How can I tell Mockito to check for both values?

Comment: when u have 2 methods with different signature, you could write separate test case for both.

Comment: Yes, but in this case its the same method signature but just different argument values

Comment: you could make try to use `Mockito.reset()`

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Further reading has led me to try using ArgumentCaptors and the following works, although much more verbose than I would like.

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

verify(errors, atLeastOnce()).add(argument.capture(), any(ActionMessage.class));

List<String> values = argument.getAllValues();

assertTrue(values.contains("exception.message"));
assertTrue(values.contains("exception.detail"));
```

Comment: is there a way to make sure that certain parameters were paired using this approach? Say for example the OP's method had two arguments and wanted to verify they were called together

Comment: The OP's test case calls `methodToTest()` exactly once, therefore this answer does verify that the two calls are made together. The captured `List<String> values` that is being asserted will only contain the two values being tested and no others. You could also add `assertTrue(values.size == 2)`. If this is what you want I would replace the 3 assertTrue statements with a single [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.1/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) ... `assertThat(values, contains("exception.message", "exception.detail"));`

Comment: doesn't OP's test case call methodToTest() twice?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I was referring to the scenario where OP wanted to test that two arguments were called in conjunction. So the method signature would look something like public void methodToTest( Exception e, Message m, ActionErrors errors ) { so that a specific exception gets called with a specific message. I supposed that you could just have two ArgumentCaptors and then retrieve the index and compare using the values at those indexes in both values lists

Comment: OP's test case calls `methodToTest()` once. It is the method argument `ActionErrors errors` is internally called twice.

Answer (score 80):

If the order of both `add()` calls is relevant, you can use `InOrder`:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(errors);
inOrder.verify(errors).add(eq("exception.message"), any(ActionError.class));
inOrder.verify(errors).add(eq("exception.detail"), any(ActionError.class));
```

Comment: It is enough to pass single `errors` argument: 
     `InOrder inOrder = inOrder(errors);` (see [docs](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification))

Comment: What if the order is NOT relevant? which is often the case.

Comment: @haelix In that case, use Brads answer. Convert the `List` to `Set` and assert that the Set of inputs equals the set given by the argument captures.

Answer (score 27):

Try something like this:

```
verify(errors, times(2))
     .add(AdditionalMatchers.or(eq("exception.message"), eq("exception.detail")),
          any(ActionError.class));
```

Comment: Your check is obviously too relaxed.

Comment: but this also success if only `exception.message` or only `exception.details` called exactly twice

Answer (score 24):

You can use `Mockito.atLeastOnce()` which allows Mockito to pass the test even if that mockObject will be called many times.

```
Mockito.verify(mockObject, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).testMethod(Mockito.eq(1));

Mockito.verify(mockObject, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).testMethod(Mockito.eq(2));
```

Comment: As a third check, you can add `Mockito.verify(mockObject, Mockito.times(2)).testMethod(Mockito.any());`. Together those checks guarantee that the method is called exactly once with each argument.

Answer (score 19):

you probably have a problem in your code. Because as a matter of fact you actually write this code:

```
Map<Character, String> map = mock(Map.class);

map.put('a', "a");
map.put('b', "b");
map.put('c', "c");

verify(map).put(eq('c'), anyString());
verify(map).put(eq('a'), anyString());
verify(map).put(eq('b'), anyString());
```

Note the first verify is not even in order in regard of the actual invocations.

Also, I would recommand you to actually don't mock types you don't own, eg the struts type.

**[EDIT @Brad]**

After running Brice's code (above) in my IDE I can see that I have used ActionError instead of ActionMessage, so that is why my verify() was not matching. The error message I initially posted was misleading me into thinking it was the first argument that was not matching. It turns out it was the second argument.

So the answer to my question is

```
/** 
 * note that ActionMessageFactory.createErrorMessage() returns ActionMessage
 * and ActionError extends ActionMessage
 */
verify(errors).add(eq("exception.message"), any(ActionMessage.class));
verify(errors).add(eq("exception.detail"), any(ActionMessage.class));
```

Comment: Don`t get what you are trying to say. Is order of verification matters? if verification order do matters. Why then here is InOrder api provided?

Comment: Just like what is written above verification order is irrelevant ; that's why there's `InOrder`.

Answer (score 11):

## OP code is correct (check your Total)

=1= Tell Mokito the total call expectation.

=2= Tell Mokito how many times each parameter combination was expected. (Mokito assumes **times(1)**, if **times** is omitted).

```
verify(errors, times(2)).add(any(), any(ActionMessage.class));

verify(errors).add(eq("exception.message"), any());
verify(errors).add(eq("exception.detail"), any());
```

The OP code is correct; it checks what you need.

Your problem was in your Prod code, which (seems) never called the first arg combination with **ActionError** arg type. So Mokito correctly complained. However (I agree) the complaint message is confusing for the multiple calls.

SOLUTION: Ensure (first of all) you really called the method precisely 2 times (with any args).

Answer (score 4):

In a similar way to @sendon1928 we can use:

```
Mockito.times(wantedInvocationCount)
```

to make sure method was called exact number of times (preferable solution in my opinion). Afterwards, we can call

```
Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock)
```

To make sure that mock was not used further in any context. Full example:

```
Mockito.verify(mockObject, Mockito.times(wantedInvocationCount)).testMethod(Mockito.eq(1));

Mockito.verify(mockObject, Mockito.times(wantedInvocationCount)).testMethod(Mockito.eq(2));

Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockObject)
```