# ArgumentCaptor vs InOrder to verify subsequent callbacks with different arguments

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I was testing my DAO class generated using the `Room` library from `Architecture Components`. I wanted to check that the `LiveData` returned by a query joining multiple tables was going to be updated when data changes.

I started out by using `InOrder` verification, but found that whatever argument I wanted to assert, Mockito would say that the method was invoked with a different one (and when I changed the assertion to that one, it would say it was the other one).

Using an `ArgumentCaptor` turned out to work fine for this purpose, which is the subject of this question:

#### Why does `ArgumentCaptor` verification work here, but `InOrder` does not?

Looking at the answers to question on [how to verify multiple method calls with different params](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8504074/1916449), both methods should work fine.

Here's a simplified version of my test that showcases the issue:

```
package com.example

import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.argumentCaptor
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.check
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito.*
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner

@Suppress("IllegalIdentifier")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MultipleCallbacksVanillaTest {

    private val java = Language("Java")
    private val javascript = Language("JavaScript")
    private val kotlin = Language("Kotlin")

    private val firstList = emptyList<Language>()
    private val secondList = listOf(java)
    private val thirdList = listOf(java, javascript, kotlin)
    private val lastList = listOf(java, kotlin)

    @Test fun `using argument captor`() {
        // given
        val observer = mock<Observer<List<Language>>>()
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<Language>>()

        // when
        liveData.observeForever(observer)
        liveData.value = firstList
        liveData.value = secondList
        liveData.value = thirdList
        liveData.value = lastList

        // then
        argumentCaptor<List<Language>>().run {
            verify(observer, times(4)).onChanged(capture())
            val (firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, lastValue) = allValues
            assertEquals(firstList, firstValue)
            assertEquals(secondList, secondValue)
            assertEquals(thirdList, thirdValue)
            assertEquals(lastList, lastValue)
        }
    }

    @Test fun `using in order`() {
        // given
        val observer = mock<Observer<List<Language>>>()
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<Language>>()

        // when
        liveData.observeForever(observer)
        liveData.value = firstList
        liveData.value = secondList
        liveData.value = thirdList
        liveData.value = lastList

        // then
        inOrder(observer).run {
            verify(observer).onChanged(check { assertEquals(firstList, it) })
            verify(observer).onChanged(check { assertEquals(secondList, it) })
            verify(observer).onChanged(check { assertEquals(thirdList, it) })
            verify(observer).onChanged(check { assertEquals(lastList, it) })
        }
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(observer)
    }

}

data class Language(val name: String)

interface Observer<in T> {
    fun onChanged(value: T?)
}

class MutableLiveData<T : Any> {
    var value: T
        get() = _value
        set(value) {
            observers.forEach { it.onChanged(value) }
            _value = value
        }

    private lateinit var _value: T

    private var observers = mutableSetOf<Observer<T>>()

    fun observeForever(observer: Observer<T>) {
        if (::_value.isInitialized) observer.onChanged(_value)
        observers.add(observer)
    }
}
```

`using argument captor` passes, but `using in order` fails with a message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected :[]
Actual   :[Language(name=Java)]
```

Comment: If possible, it would be very preferable if you could minimise the number of libraries your test case depends on (specifically Android / Google Truth), unless they're required to invoke the problem.

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - This appears to be a bug and/or bad documentation on [Mockito-Kotlin's](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) part, in terms of its `check` function.

Mockito-Kotlin's [wiki says](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki/Mocking-and-verifying#argument-matchers):

> If you want to do more assertions on the received argument, you can use `check`.  [...]  If you want your test to fail inside a `check` invocation, you should make sure the body throws an error [...]

The implementation of `check` [calls Mockito's `argThat`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/master/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L87), and passes the supplied predicate as an argument.  However, [the documentation for `ArgumentMatcher` states](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html#matches(T)):

> The method should never assert if the argument doesn't match. It should only return `false`.

Thus Mockito-Kotlin's documentation is in direct contradiction with this constraint.

I'm not sure how to fix this, but you could just avoid `check` entirely for now, and use `argThat` directly (returning `false` as appropriate, rather than throwing).

Comment: FWIW, I've submitted this as [an issue against Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/231).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that indeed is the issue. I actually like the argument captor better here (it's more concise), nevertheless using `argThat` like you say works around the issue (I posted the code in a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `check` (instead of the one provided by Mockito-Kotlin) function like this seems to work fine:

```
inline fun <reified T> check(noinline predicate: (T?) -> Unit): T? {
    return Mockito.argThat {
        try {
            predicate(it)
            true
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

This issue has been fixed in [2.0.0-alpha04](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha04) version of mockito-kotlin.