Mockito argThat() invoked multiple times unexpectedly
I am using Mockito to test this method below. I want to test database.save() is called twice, once with id, and once without id.
@Service
public class ScenarioService {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseService database;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> duplicateScenario() {

        Scenario scenario1 = new Scenario(null, "scenario1");
        Scenario scenario2 = new Scenario("100", "scenario2");

        database.save(scenario1);
        database.save(scenario2);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}

I am following the solution here to verify multiple method calls with different params https://stackoverflow.com/a/34204883/5777189
But I am getting a weird behavior with argThat() instead of being invoked twice with just the parameters of each call. It is invoked 6 times. I just need an explanation.
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class scenarioTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    DatabaseService database;

    @Test
    public void duplicateScenario() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = post("/scenarios/duplicate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .characterEncoding("utf-8");

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(database);
        inOrder.verify(database).save(argThat(scenario -> {
            System.out.println(scenario);
            // printed 6 times
//            Scenario{id='null', name='scenario1'}
//            Scenario{id='100', name='scenario2'}
//            Scenario{id='null', name='scenario1'}
//            Scenario{id='100', name='scenario2'}
//            Scenario{id='null', name='scenario1'}
//            Scenario{id='100', name='scenario2'}
            return true;
        }));
    }
}

Demo project:
https://github.com/yatw/mockitotest/blob/master/src/test/java/com/yatw/mockitotest/scenarioTest.java

Why do you find it unexpected? Mockito does multiple passes over stubbed invocations 1) For each actual invocation, it needs to find a stub that matches 2) It checks missing invocations 3) It checks extra invocations.

From your code, database.save() should called exactly twice. You can use inOrder.verify(database, times(2)).save(any()) to verify it.

ok I will accept that's how Mockito works internally.
Although it is invoked multiple times, Mockito Inorder does work with argThat().
It uses the return inside argThat() to determine if the method is invoked in the right order. My example above fail because it is hard coded to always return true. For the verify to pass, it need to return true for the intended argument, and need to fail all the other invalid invocations.
InOrder inOrder = Mockito.InOrder(database);
inOrder.verify(database).save(argThat(scenario-> scenario.getId() == null));
inOrder.verify(database).save(argThat(scenario-> Objects.equals(scenario.getId(), "100")));

